# Status=Accepted, StatusCode=202 but not gettting SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am able to send Test SMS using Marketing Cloud Mobile Connect. When I am trying to send through the API, I am getting this response:

> Status=Accepted, StatusCode=202

When I look into the error code documentation it says:

> 202 - Singlepoint Billing Received -
>    Singlepoint billing DR

So it looks like some kind of contract/billing but not sure, asked marketing cloud support but they are taking some time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

They are actually Status Codes, not Errors (not to be confused):
a 202 status code usually indicates:

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
>   not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted
>   upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.

Without any details as to what it is you are attempting (api reference wise), it is kind of hard to provide an accurate answer, and I am guessing that by now, support has either replied to you and your case set to resolved, or your request was actually processed by the server. (if not, support might have provided feedback and you should actually update your post, or provide an answer to your own question)